# combobox with images in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datagrid

i want to fill a datagrid with the columns "Datum" (DateTime), "Aktion" (String), "Wer" (string),"BisWann" (DateTime), "Status" (int). The "Status" column should be a dropdown list, which contains four icons and dependent on the int value, there should be the correct image preselected.

how can i archive this? So far, i have the datagrid filled with every value, except the dropdownlist (in the following code just a sample entry w/o database)

Window.xaml:

```
<DataGrid Name="dgMassnahmen" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="10,10,10,10" Grid.Row="1">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Datum" Binding="{Binding Datum, StringFormat=\{0:dd.MM.yy\}}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Aktion" Binding="{Binding Aktion}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Wer" Binding="{Binding Wer}"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="BisWann">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding BisWann}" BorderThickness="0" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Status" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Status}"/>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

the Itemclass:

```
public class Massnahmen
{
    public DateTime Datum { get; set; }
    public string Aktion { get; set; }
    public string Wer { get; set; }
    public DateTime BisWann { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
}
```

in Window.xaml.cs:

```
private void FillMassnahmen()
{
    List<Klassen.Massnahmen> massnahmen = new List<Klassen.Massnahmen>();
    massnahmen.Add(new Klassen.Massnahmen() { Datum = DateTime.Now, Aktion = "DoSomething", BisWann = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2), Status = 2, Wer = "OfCourseYOU" });
    dgMassnahmen.ItemsSource = massnahmen;
}
```

Comment: Where and how do you define the int values to choose from and your icons?

Comment: well, it's seems like you don't set `ItemsSource` for `ComboBox`

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `ItemsSource` to an array of `Image` elements and set the `Tag` property of each element to an `int` value that you bind to the Status property:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Status"
                        SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Status}"
                        SelectedValuePath="Tag"
                        xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type Image}">
            <Image Source="1.png">
                <Image.Tag>
                    <s:Int32>1</s:Int32>
                </Image.Tag>
            </Image>
            <Image Source="2.png">
                <Image.Tag>
                    <s:Int32>2</s:Int32>
                </Image.Tag>
            </Image>
        </x:Array>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Comment: @Hraaig: Did you try this?